# Path is not a valid virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net

The below method takes a path pointing to an XML file:

```
tree.LoadContentFile(path);
```

I pass a complete path from my local file system (or use `Server.MapPath()`), but every time I keep getting this error:

> [Path] is not a valid virtual path.

I am using Telerik RadTreeView.

A sample path is: `"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename\OutlookNavigation\tree.xml"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

.NET is expecting a path like

```
~/folder/file.txt
```

or

`/folder/file.txt`

which it will translate into a physical path.