# folder deleting not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

```vb
If System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("images/TravelogueGallery/" & getMaxID())) Then
    System.IO.Directory.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("images/TravelogueGallery/" & getMaxID()), True)
End If
```

I am using the above code snippet to delete a directory but I get this error:

> 'G:\Projects\Latest\LTCIndia 05-04-12 1415\images\TravelogueGallery\19' is not a valid virtual path.

What's wrong with the code?

**UPDATE:** I have updated the question with the correct answer. The above code snippet works just fine. Thanks guys for your time.

Comment: Remove the MapPath on the delete line. See if that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942514/is-not-a-valid-virtual-path

Comment: ain't there any problem with the space caracter?

Comment: Fixed ...i had two `Server.MapPath` in the syntax `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Server.MapPath(`

Comment: @user1150440 Please post the fix as an answer and (after the cooldown period) accept it, so the question appears answered when searched for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("images/TravelogueGallery/" & getMaxID())) Then
    System.IO.Directory.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("images/TravelogueGallery/" & getMaxID()), True)
End If
```

This is the correct answer.
I have updated the question with the correct answer. The above code snippet works just fine. Thanks guys for your time.